# How should I charge storage fees?

Tags: nearprotocol

What are the best practices of charging storage frees from user? Will I have to charge the storage fees every time they insert the data?
Can I charge storage fees without making a function `[payable]`?

Answer (score 3):

> What are the best practices of charging storage frees from user?

There is a Standard designed for this use case:

- [Storage Management](https://nomicon.io/Standards/StorageManagement.html) ([NEP-145](https://github.com/near/NEPs/discussions/145))

You can use the interface of this standard in rust from [this implementation](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/master/near-contract-standards/src/storage_management/mod.rs) in near-sdk-rs.

In particular one useful example, is the [implementation of this trait for FungibleToken](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/master/near-contract-standards/src/fungible_token/storage_impl.rs#L40). This functions are exposed using [this macro](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/master/near-contract-standards/src/fungible_token/macros.rs#L71).

> Will I have to charge the storage fees every time they insert the data?

If it is clear what is the amount of data a single user requires, they only need to call `storage_deposit` once, with the required deposit. Optionally they can call `storage_withdraw` / `storage_unregister` to get a refund and remove their data.

> Can I charge storage fees without making a function [payable]?

No. But if you follow previous standard, only `storage_deposit` needs to be `#[payable]` and not other functions in your contract.